# Getting 401 error in jenkins job during Nexus deplyment

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, nexus, unauthorized

I have a Jenkins job with Nexus and GitLab integration. When deploying the repo in nexus it's giving 401 error.

I have checked this error is unauthorization, but I have tried with my credentials. I have added test usrs and tried with that. Even added the user in settings.xml, still the error persists.

These are the console logs:

```
21:51:31  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project webcontoc-utility-core: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.cedac.webcontoc:webcontoc-utility-core:jar:2.0.0 from/to nex-ib-prod-caripark-snapshots : Failed to transfer file with status code 401 -> [Help 1]
21:51:31  [ERROR] 
21:51:31  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
21:51:31  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
21:51:31  [ERROR] 
21:51:31  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
21:51:31  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }

21:51:32  error..=hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
21:51:31  No test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

If anyone has any idea about the error, please share your views..
That would be very helpful.